# What is the best way to get to production from the Git Flow branching model?

Tags: git, git-flow

I have recently joined a new team of developers and we are incorporating Git and Git Flow branching models into our work environments.

So far we have the develop and master branches set up in our remote repo. The develop branch has an automatic hook that deploys code to our staging area when a push is seen. I have also just created a tag containing production ready code.

My question now is what is the best, or industry standard, way to move to production from this state?

Some options I see are:

1. Clone the repo from the tag version at the production location. Then in the future do pulls from newly created tags.
2. Perform a command similar to this `git archive <tag> | tar -x -C /path/to/live/site` manually every time we want to go to production with a new tag.

Comment: Both are valid options. I prefer the first one. So what are your concerns? As a sidenote: Don't do any of both manually, but create a deploy script, or use a tool like capistrano, or similar.

Comment: Thanks @KingCrunch. I think we're going to do it manually to begin with as we need to get some releases out the door. But in the future I would def script one of the two methods.

Capistrano is definitely something I've also thought about.

Comment: I recommend to start as soon as possible with such task, especially because the most simple solution is to put everything you type manually into a shell script and call this instead ;) But this way you (and other devs) will never forget, what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer strategy mentioned [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). You may want to read in details ?

Comment: I am using that strategy. Git Flow is that branching model exactly.

Comment: What it doesn't describe is a working process for getting code into a production environment.